# grep error of function

Tags: bash, function, grep

I have a set of functions that get run from an array. This part works as expected. I'm adding some error checking and want to detect when a function fails. It may fail because some of the functions reside in a different file and if that file is not present, when the function tries to run it will output "command not found". I'd like to detect that so I can halt the program and alert the user.

```
for i in "${!FUNCTION[@]}"; do
  ${FUNCTION[$i]} | grep "command not found" then BLAH="fail";
```

Basically im just trying to set a variable if it fails which I'll use further down:

```
if [ "$BLAH" = "fail" ]; then
    echo "OOPS"
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `then` needs `if` before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ${FUNCTION[$i]} | grep "command not found" 
then BLAH="fail"
fi
```

It would be better if your functions exited with a non-zero status when they failed. Then you could write:

```
${FUNCTION[$i]} || BLAH=fail
```